# Sending an voice file to API (laravel) - 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send a voice file to my api built in laravel. Everything seems right in my code but when i send the file to my api, i check at my api side if the data posted has file contained in it but i keep getting **false**. Am i posting my voice file wrongly.

Path: Absolute path

PHP version : 7.0

```
 $endPoint = 'https://api.domain.com/api';
        $apiKey = '**********';
        $url = $endPoint . '?key=' . $apiKey;
        $curlFile = new \CurlFile('/Users/public/Voice/aaaah.wav');
        $data = [
           'message' => 'First Voice',
           'file' => $curlFile,
        ];  
        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        curl_close($ch);     
        return $result;
```

Comment: shouldn't this be $url = $endPoint . '?key=' . $Key;

Comment: $apiKey variable seems undefined.

Comment: thanks. it was just a typo

Comment: also is this a typo? $curlFile = new \CurlFile('/Users/public/Voice/aaaah.wav');
should there be a backslash before CurlFile?